# How to add items to Dictionary

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to create a TemplateSelector which recognizes if an implements an interface and applies a DataTemplate for it.

I'd like to use this selector in following way:

```
<ListView Grid.Column="0" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Media}"
    SelectionMode="None">
    <ListView.ItemTemplateSelector>
        <selectors:InterfaceAwareTemplateSelector>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="IMedia">
                <Image Source="{Binding PreviewImage}" />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="IDocument">
                <TextBlock Text="test" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </selectors:InterfaceAwareTemplateSelector>
    </ListView.ItemTemplateSelector>
</ListView>
```

I end up with following implementation:

```
[ContentProperty(Name = "Items")]
public class InterfaceAwareTemplateSelector: DataTemplateSelector {
    public DataTemplate DefaultTemplate { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<Type, DataTemplate> Items { get; set; }

    public InterfaceAwareTemplateSelector() {
        Items = new Dictionary<Type, DataTemplate>();
    }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var result = (
            from t in Items 
            where t.Key.GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(item.GetType().GetTypeInfo())
            select t.Value).FirstOrDefault();


        return result ?? DefaultTemplate;
    }
}
```

It of course doesn't work, otherwise I wouldn't write this question :) Application crushes with a message a xaml cannot be parsed:

```
A first chance exception of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in Hicron.ProductCatalog.MainUI.exe
WinRT information: E_UNKNOWN_ERROR [Line: 47 Position: 39]
An exception of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in Hicron.ProductCatalog.MainUI.exe but was not handled in user code
WinRT information: E_UNKNOWN_ERROR [Line: 47 Position: 39]
Additional information: Unspecified error
```

What's wrong with that dictionary? Normally I'd use CompositeCollection and merge multiple sources but this class is missing in WinRT :(

**EDIT**
In terms of fixing dictionary problem I've changed dictionary to list of custom types. Still can't create a custom type with Type set from XAML. I could use a string but than I can't manage it in code unless I specify fully qualified type name.

```
[ContentProperty(Name = "Items")]
public class InterfaceAwareTemplateSelector: DataTemplateSelector {
    public DataTemplate DefaultTemplate { get; set; }
    public List<InterfaceAwareTemplateSelectorItem> Items { get; set; }

    public InterfaceAwareTemplateSelector() {
        Items = new List<InterfaceAwareTemplateSelectorItem>();
    }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container) {
        if (item == null) {
            return DefaultTemplate;
        }

        var result = (
            from t in Items
            where t.Type.GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(item.GetType().GetTypeInfo())
            select t.Template).FirstOrDefault();


        return result ?? DefaultTemplate;
    }
}

public class InterfaceAwareTemplateSelectorItem
{
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate Template { get; set; }
}
```

Corresponding XAML:

```
        // somewhere in page tag  
        xmlns:bo="using:/*long long namespace*/.BusinessObjects"  

        // somewhere in XAML file
        <ListView Grid.Column="0" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Media}"
            SelectionMode="None">
            <ListView.ItemTemplateSelector>
                <selectors:InterfaceAwareTemplateSelector>
                    <selectors:InterfaceAwareTemplateSelectorItem Type="bo:IMedia">
                        <selectors:InterfaceAwareTemplateSelectorItem.Template>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Image Source="{Binding PreviewImage}"
                                       Tapped="ImageTapped" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </selectors:InterfaceAwareTemplateSelectorItem.Template>
                    </selectors:InterfaceAwareTemplateSelectorItem>
                    <selectors:InterfaceAwareTemplateSelectorItem Type="bo:IDocument">
                        <selectors:InterfaceAwareTemplateSelectorItem.Template>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="pa8u4mrapwu" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </selectors:InterfaceAwareTemplateSelectorItem.Template>
                    </selectors:InterfaceAwareTemplateSelectorItem>
                </selectors:InterfaceAwareTemplateSelector>
            </ListView.ItemTemplateSelector>
        </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to fix it. Unfortunately I couldn't get a conversion from string to Type in XAML so I had to stick to strings :/ Not very convenient but at least works. That's what I ended up with:

XAML

```
<ListView Grid.Column="0" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Media}"
    SelectionMode="None">
    <ListView.ItemTemplateSelector>
        <selectors:InterfaceAwareTemplateSelector>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="IMedia">
                <Image Source="{Binding PreviewImage}" Tapped="ImageTapped"/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="IDocument">
                <commonItems:DocumentItemPresenter TappedCommand="{Binding DataContext.OpenDocument, ElementName=PageRoot}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </selectors:InterfaceAwareTemplateSelector>
    </ListView.ItemTemplateSelector>
</ListView>
```

Selector itself:

```
[ContentProperty(Name = "Items")]
public class InterfaceAwareTemplateSelector: DataTemplateSelector {
    public DataTemplate DefaultTemplate { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, DataTemplate> Items { get; set; }

    public InterfaceAwareTemplateSelector() {
        Items = new Dictionary<string, DataTemplate>();
    }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container) {
        if (item == null) {
            return DefaultTemplate;
        }

        var result = (
            from ii in item.GetType().GetTypeInfo().ImplementedInterfaces
            from dt in Items
            where ii.Name == dt.Key
            select dt.Value).FirstOrDefault();

        return result ?? DefaultTemplate;
    }
}
```

I upvoted Filip & Jerry because I found your tips helpful. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so using this:

```
public interface IFake1 { }
public interface IFake2 { }
public class TemplateItem
{
    public DataTemplate Template { get; set; }
    public string Interface { get; set; }
}
public class MySelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public List<TemplateItem> Templates { get; set; }
}
```

I could do this:

```
<GridView>
    <GridView.ItemTemplateSelector>
        <local:MySelector>
            <local:MySelector.Templates>
                <local:TemplateItem Interface="IFake1">
                    <local:TemplateItem.Template>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <!-- TODO -->
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </local:TemplateItem.Template>
                </local:TemplateItem>
                <local:TemplateItem Interface="IFake2">
                    <local:TemplateItem.Template>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <!-- TODO -->
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </local:TemplateItem.Template>
                </local:TemplateItem>
            </local:MySelector.Templates>
        </local:MySelector>
    </GridView.ItemTemplateSelector>
</GridView>
```

The error appears in the `Type` you are using. I could not get that to work. Had to use `String`. Should be simple to parse form there.

Best of luck!

Comment: Yep, that's what I did as a intermediate step to my solution. I also couldn't get string->type conversions in XAML working :/ Thanks for tips anyway

Comment: Honestly, I think this might just be your solution.

Answer (score 0):

See if it works if you replace `Dictionary<Type, DataTemplate>` with `ResourceDictionary`. I'm betting at least one of the problems is that the key in `x:Key="IMedia"` can't be implicitly converted to `Type`. You could also just try using `string` as the key type.

Comment: Yep, changing to Type is one point of the story. I cannot actually use strings instead of Types because I won't be able to construct the type based on string unless I have a fully qualified string. Please, check my edit.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to use types directly in XAML. Use type names in XAML and either use a switch block in code behind and a list of accepted types or use reflection to find the type that matches the string value.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested how this problem was solved below is final implementation and a usage example.

Usage:

```
    <GridView ....>
        <GridView.ItemTemplateSelector>
            <selectors:InterfaceAwareTemplateSelector>
                <!-- ReSharper disable once Xaml.RedundantResource -->
                <DataTemplate x:Key="INewsContainer" selectors:InterfaceAwareTemplateSelector.Priority="1">
                    <ctrls:ItemsContainerTile Width="350" Height="350"
                        ItemTappedCommand="{Binding DataContext.OpenNewsDetails, ElementName=PageRoot}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
                <!-- ReSharper disable once Xaml.RedundantResource -->
                <DataTemplate x:Key="ISimpleMaterial" selectors:InterfaceAwareTemplateSelector.Priority="0">
                    <ctrls:GenericTile Width="350" Height="350"
                        TappedCommand="{Binding DataContext.OpenDetails, ElementName=PageRoot}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </selectors:InterfaceAwareTemplateSelector>
        </GridView.ItemTemplateSelector>
   .... the rest of XAML
```

The priority is to control the order in which datatamples should be checked. This way we can control what happens if multiple keys matches the object being converted.

Implementation:

```
[ContentProperty(Name = "Items")]
public class InterfaceAwareTemplateSelector: DataTemplateSelector {
    public DataTemplate DefaultTemplate { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, DataTemplate> Items { get; set; }

    public InterfaceAwareTemplateSelector() {
        Items = new Dictionary<string, DataTemplate>();
    }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container) {
        if (item == null) {
            return DefaultTemplate;
        }

        var results = (
            from ii in item.GetType().GetTypeInfo().ImplementedInterfaces
            from dt in Items
            where ii.Name == dt.Key
            select dt)
            .ToArray();

        if (results.Length > 1) {
            var orderedResults =
                from r in results
                where IsPrioritySet(r.Value)
                orderby GetPriority(r.Value) descending
                select r;

            if (orderedResults.Any()) {
                return orderedResults.First().Value;
            }

            throw new AmbigiousResolveTemplateFound(item.GetType(), results.Select(x => x.Key));
        }
        else if (results.Length == 1) {
            return results[0].Value;
        }

        return DefaultTemplate;
    }

    #region PriorityProperty
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PriorityProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Priority",
            typeof(int),
            typeof(InterfaceAwareTemplateSelector),
            new PropertyMetadata(0));

    public static int GetPriority(DependencyObject item) {
        if (item == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("item"); }

        return (int)item.GetValue(PriorityProperty);
    }

    public static void SetPriority(DependencyObject item, int value) {
        if (item == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("item"); }

        item.SetValue(PriorityProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool IsPrioritySet(DependencyObject item) {
        if (item == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("item"); }

        var result = item.ReadLocalValue(PriorityProperty);
        return result != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Hope someone will find this implementation helpful. Once again, many thanks to Filip and Jerry for your help.